# Api Platform Date Filter not working with datetime fields

Tags: symfony, date, datetime, filter, api-platform.com

I have a Control entity who have a dateTime field (i need date and time for this object). I also need to get my controls who ar into a period (just a date)

Because the DateTime Filter does not exist i'm using the DateFilter of api platform

Here my @ApiFilter :

```
@ApiFilter(SearchFilter::class, properties={"customer" : "exact", "customer.subscriber":"exact"},
 *              DateFilter::class, properties={"dateTime":"partial"})
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=ControlRepository::class)
```

And here my entity

```
class Control
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @Groups({"customer:read", "control:read", "subscriber:read"})
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
     * @Groups({"customer:read", "control:read", "subscriber:read"})
     */
    private $dateTime;
```

When i send a GET request to

```
http://localhost:8000/api/controls?dateTime[after]=2021-05-12
```

My application return HTTP 500 : This annotation needs a value representing the filter class

But date and datetime are suposed to be compatible. Even if i add 00:00:00 next to my date my application send me the same message and all my others requests to.

Anyone know how i can filter by date my entities without this error ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the DateFilter like this:

```
@ApiFilter(DateFilter::class, properties={"dateTime"})
```

Also change this:

```
/**
* @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
* @Groups({"customer:read", "control:read", "subscriber:read"})
*/
private $dateTime;
```

to

```
/**
* @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
* @Groups({"customer:read", "control:read", "subscriber:read"})
* @var \DateTime
*/
private $dateTime;
```